# Emacs -- tree-view libraries that show date modified, size, permissions, etc

Tags: emacs

I have modified ztree-mode to provide a tree-view with a few of the dired-mode features -- e.g., mark, unmark, `ztree-get-marked-files`, up-directory, copy, rename/move, delete, sort by name and sort by modified date.  I'm looking to take the major-mode to the next step, which is include some additional information -- e.g., modified date, size (human readable -- e.g. kb, MB, GB), permissions, etc.  However, I haven't found a comparable library from which to get some ideas from.  Are there any tree-view libraries that offer a visual display of some of those file-attributes details?

Essentially, I'll be using the data returned from `(directory-files-and-attributes DIRECTORY t nil t)` and organizing the tree view based on the additional details that list offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There do not appear to be any Emacs tree-view libraries publicly available that presently offer this feature.

Therefore, I will create such a feature myself.  The following function can be used to obtain a custom list of file-name, size, date and permissions.  The function `file-size-human-readable` may not be available in earlier versions of Emacs, but it is available in Emacs Trunk.  The function `ls-lisp-format-file-size` in `ls-lisp` is an alternative, but it produces a result with leading whitespace -- I chose not to use that one, rather than fiddle with it.  The `message` is not needed, but is helpful to see what the custom-list looks like -- just for demonstration purposes.

```lisp
(defun random-sort--filename-size-date-permissions ()
"Return a custom list (sorted randomly):
  absolute name, size, date and permissions."
  (let* (
      (directory "~/")
      (master (directory-files-and-attributes directory t nil t nil))
      (custom-list (mapcar (lambda (x)
        (list
          (nth 0 x) ;; filename
          (file-size-human-readable (nth 8 x)) ;; size
          (format-time-string "%m-%d-%Y %R" (nth 6 x)) ;; date
          (nth 9 x) )) ;; permissions
        master)) )
    (dolist (x custom-list)
      (message "%s" x))
    custom-list))

(defun date-sort--filename-size-date-permissions ()
"Return a custom list (sorted by date -- newest first):
  absolute name, size, date and permissions."
  (let* (
      (directory "~/")
      (random-master (directory-files-and-attributes directory t nil t nil))
      (date-sort--master (sort random-master
        #'(lambda (x y) (time-less-p (nth 6 y) (nth 6 x)))))
      (custom-list (mapcar (lambda (x)
        (list
          (nth 0 x) ;; filename
          (file-size-human-readable (nth 8 x)) ;; size
          (format-time-string "%m-%d-%Y %R" (nth 6 x)) ;; date
          (nth 9 x) )) ;; permissions
        date-sort--master)) )
    (dolist (x custom-list)
      (message "%s" x))
    custom-list))

(defun alpha-sort--filename-size-date-permissions ()
"Return a custom list (sorted alphabetically):
  absolute name, size, date and permissions."
  (let* (
      (directory "~/")
      (alpha-sort--master (directory-files-and-attributes directory t nil nil nil))
      (custom-list (mapcar (lambda (x)
        (list
          (nth 0 x) ;; filename
          (file-size-human-readable (nth 8 x)) ;; size
          (format-time-string "%m-%d-%Y %R" (nth 6 x)) ;; date
          (nth 9 x) )) ;; permissions
        alpha-sort--master)) )
    (dolist (x custom-list)
      (message "%s" x))
    custom-list))
```

---

**Sort by Name** using a slight variation of the function `alpha-sort--filename-size-date-permissions`, with a custom modified version of `ztree-mode`:

[image: Example]

---

**Sort by Date** using a slight variation of the function `date-sort--filename-size-date-permissions`, with a custom modified version of `ztree-mode`:

[image: Example]